# C# query with count

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of users having several properties and I want to know who and how had the same code (which is an user property)

For example :

- user 1: Jacob, code 1
- user 2: Charlie, code 1
- user 3: Thomas, code 2

I need to query and have a result like this :

```
+--------+--------+
| Object |  Count |
+--------+--------+
| user 1 |    2   |
| user 2 |    2   |
| user 3 |    1   |
+--------+--------+
```

"2" because 2 users have the same code and "1" because just one had the code

Can someone help me for this please?

Comment: StackOverflow is not where people write codes for you, but where people solve problems. Next time, try to post also what have you tried so far and the reason why it's not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get using this linq. change `tablename` and `field name` according to yours.

```
(from user in _context.Users
             let count = _context.Users.Where(p=>p.code == user.code).Count()
                 select new {user.username, count = count}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Let's  try below code. I think it can help you well:**

```
var result = mycontext.users.GroupBy(p=>p.User).Select(p=>new { Object  = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
```